# Is the tangent bundle of a submanifold a submanifold of the tangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

If $N\subset M$ is an immersed submanifold of a smooth manifold $M$, is its tangent bundle $TN$ an immersed submanifold of $TM$?

In other words: If $\iota:N\to M$ is the immersion (smooth map with injective differential), is its differential $d\iota:TN\to TM $ also an immersion?

Intuitively, I think that the answer is yes but I have trouble proving it.

Comment: First try to understand the smooth structure on TM i.e which are the charts, then see what happens when you restrict that charts to TN.

Comment: Hint: if $\iota \colon N \to M$ is the inclusion, what can you say about its differential $\mathrm{d}\iota \colon TN \to TM$?

Comment: @Didier I guess if $\iota$ is the inclusion and it is an immersion, then $d\iota$ should be injective. Is this correct? Does this somehow imply that $TN$ is a submanifold of $TM$?

Comment: What is the definition of submanifold you are using? They are all equivalent, but some will be preferable to others.

Comment: @Laz By submanifold I mean what is called an immersed submanifold. That is, the inclusion $\iota: N\to M$ is a smooth map with injective derivative (immersion). I would like to know if its derivative $d\iota:TN\to TM$ is also an immersion, besides injective. The derivative of $d\iota$ should be $0$ because $d^2=0$, which is why I am confused.